# How to increment the result of division when it contains remainder of the division?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Maybe this question was asked previously but I didn't find a solution of my problem. So, I have one number like `general count` and I have to get the result of division. But, I have to increment the result if it contains remainder. I tried to create own function:

```
 private fun mod(count: Int): Double {
        val mainCount: Double
        val remainder = count % 50

        mainCount = if (remainder > 0) {
            count.toDouble() / 50+1
        } else {
            count.toDouble() / 50
        }

        return mainCount
    }
```

but it didn't help, then I used this function:

```
val df = DecimalFormat("0")
df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN
Log.i("m", df.format(count/50).toString())
```

but in logs I get the main number without remainder. For example I have smth like that:

```
main count - 112
result of division - 2.24
what I want to get - 3
```

Maybe I did smth wrong?

Comment: so, you want 112 / 50 to return 3, or do I understand this wrong? Why would you expect that result?

Comment: yes, you are right, the result of division is the number of pages with info

Comment: ok ... but just to be clear: 112/50 does not, (and for obvious reasons) will never return 3.

Comment: yes I understand it, but maybe we have some method how to do it? I don't know :(

Comment: you can round your result up to the nearest (bigger) integer

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko have you ever use Math.ceil() method ?

Comment: @SubhashPrajapati, no I have never used it, what does it do?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko please check this link https://www.guru99.com/math-java.html

Comment: this one is giving exact what you want.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Solve your problem or not ?

Comment: @SubhashPrajapati, can you add the example, because this - ceil((count/50).toDouble()) doesn't help me and after division 112/50 it gave 2.0

Comment: Could you just use `(count + 49) / 50`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code snippet. Hope it helps.

```
    val mainCount: Double
    val remainder = count % 50

    mainCount = count.toDouble() / 50
    val finalMainCount = if (remainder > 0) {
        mainCount.toInt() + 1
    } else {
        mainCount.toInt()
    }

    println(finalMainCount)

    return finalMainCount
```

Comment: It would be better if you also explained your changes

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see, you are simply trying to round the result up.

The simplest way to do this is to add `(denominator - 1)` to the numerator. So (in Java), the entire method could be reduced to:

```
return (count + 49) / 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

just add +1 in the main court if the remainder is greater then 0 and less then 50.
like if(reminder >0 && reminder <50) mainCount++;

Comment: by adding 1, the result would be 3.24.

Comment: use the main count as integer variable then it will be 3, not 3.24 . or typeCast the main count to Integer in the end.

Comment: you have declared mainCount: Double.  instead of Double declare it as Integer